# c# datatable new column Expression datetime

Tags: c#, datatable, expression

im trying to concatenate two different datetime fields in a datatable

the problem is, that i want to concatenate only the years, and not the whole datetime string.

for concatenating the entire string:

```
newColumn = new DataColumn("concatDate");

newColumn.Expression = "Convert(StartDate, 'System.String') 
                     + Convert(EndDate , 'System.String')";
```

any suggestions will be grate!!

cheers

Comment: have you sought out any  examples on line in regards to things that you can do with `DataTable` [C# DataTable Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable)

Comment: Do you need to do it with Expression? Why not loop the table and set a real value.

Comment: What is your underlying data source?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no support for the YEAR method in the syntax recognized by the Expression property. However you could achieve your result using a very inelegant use of substring.

Something like this

```
newColumn.Expression = @"Substring(Convert(StartDate, 'System.String'), 7, 4) 
                       + Substring(Convert(EndDate, 'System.String'), 7, 4)"
```

The exact values to use for the Substring depend on your locale and on the rules applied when transforming your date in a string. So you should experiment with that 7 and 4 to adjust to your database settings